# Loop to insert values in a column based on file name and save in different directory

Tags: r, loops, directory

I am working in a folder (directory1) and I need to first modify and then use .csv files present in another folder (directory2).

First I would like to insert values in a column based on the file name; and I would like to do this in a loop for all subjects.
I know how to do it for single files, but not sure how to create the loop.

```
#Choose directory with .csv files to read
setwd("/Users/R/directory2")
d = read.table("ppt01_EvF.csv", sep=",")

#Change columns names
colnames(d) <- c("Order","Condition","Press","Response","Time","Time2")

#Read file name
filenames <- "ppt01_EvF.csv"

# Remove ".csv"
filenames2 <- sub(".csv", "", filenames)

# Split the string by "_"
filenames_vec <- strsplit(filenames2, split = "_")[[1]]

# Create new column to store the information
d$PPT_N_NUMBER <- filenames_vec[1]
```

Second, I would like to save all the .csv files as one big file containing all the participants but just one row at the top of the new big file with the columns names.

Last, I would like to save this new big file (.csv) in the folder I am working on (directory1) - so a different directory than the one the single files are stored.

I would appreciate if someone could help me to understand the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
setwd("/Users/R/directory2")
files <- list.files()
library(data.table)

data_list <- list()

for(i in 1:length(files)){
  file_name <- files[i]
  d = fread(file_name, sep=",")

  #Change columns names
  colnames(d) <- c("Order","Condition","Press","Response","Time","Time2")

  # Split the string by "_"
  filenames_vec <- strsplit(file_name, split = "_")[[1]]

  # Create new column to store the information
  d$PPT_N_NUMBER <- filenames_vec[1]
  data_list[[i]] <- d
}
all_data <- rbindlist(data_list)
fwrite(all_data, '../directory1/all_data.csv')
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! I just needed to modify `files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")`